# firebase is not defined at firebase.initializeApp(config);

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I cloned the angular-seed repo and am trying to create an app using Firebase on top of it. I have

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.5/firebase.js"></script>
```

in my HTML document, and I also have the config object set up with my apiKey, authDomain, etc. But, I get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined" in my console, at the line

```
firebase.initializeApp(config).
```

Why am I getting this error? What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: It seems most likely that the included script has not complete loaded yet by the time you execute the `firebase.initializeApp(config)` call.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think you are right. I moved the firebase script before all the other scripts and it worked. Thank you. :)

Comment: Good to hear. I'll vote to close as a minor typo, as it's unlikely others in the same situation will find this question.